# Most efficient way for passing data between two fragments

Tags: android, fragment

If I have a hosting activity of two fragments, and I want to send data from one fragment to the other (and vice versa) what would be the most efficient way to do so?

1. Implementing an interface, declaring the fragments in layout....
2. Creating a Singleton class that both fragments can use to set/get the private static variable inside the class.
3. ?

Comment: @Horace doesn't have a word about efficiency

Comment: By efficient do you mean speed?

Comment: The question in it's initial form mentioned nothing of efficiency. Are you referring to the efficiency of the developer implementing the call or the speed of execution?

Comment: speed and memory .
Thanks!

Comment: Speedwise - depending on your implementation, interfacing between the layouts is fastest. Memory usage is a tad bit more because you are going to pass the value in the parameter of the function call.

Memory wise -using static variable is the best because you don't need to "pass" it between two fragments. Though you are going to have to notify the second fragment that you have finished your "set" operation and its time to "get" it. That might not be the fastest though.

Comment: I see.. so there isn't a win-win here.. it really comes down to the priorities of speed / memory. 
Is there another way to communicate between fragments?
I know you can call setTargetFragment() but that's only if you expect a result back. What if I don't ?